# Getting project root from ede

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet

I'm trying to get root of project from ede object. I read interessting discussion about this [issue](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/A-unified-project-root-interface-td280345.html). I used an example from David which seems to work perfectly except it works only for buffers with opened files from project. I would like to have this returning root of project from dired mode or from any other mode I decide. Is it possible? Here's code I used:

```
(defun my-get-project-root ()
(interactive)
(let ((proj ede-object-root-project))
  (if proj
  (message "Project root: %s"
           (ede-project-root-directory proj))
    (message "No project for this buffer."))))
```

So when running this for instance from dired mode I get: "No project for this buffer" message.

I'm aware it can be achieved with some other tools but I'm already using cedet for my projects management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use something like:

```
(defun get-project-root-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((fname (or (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)) default-directory))
     (current-dir (file-name-directory fname))
         (prj (ede-current-project current-dir)))
    (when prj
      (ede-project-root-directory prj))))
```